# Can $\sin x$ be represented exactly on an interval by finitely many polynomial, rational, (real) exponential, and logarithmic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, trigonometry

By "representation of a part of $\sin x$" I mean a mapping from a non-zero continuous interval to $\sin x$. The condition is that it must be a composition of **finitely many** polynomial, rational, exponential, and logarithmic functions, but it **must not encompass imaginary exponentation or imaginary logs.**

Here are some examples of how *should* the function look like (the identites are fake, but the functions on the right-hand sides are reminiscent of $\sin x$):
$$\sin x=\frac{16x(\pi -x)}{5\pi ^2-4x(\pi -x)}\quad 0\le x\le \pi ,$$
$$\sin x=\frac{72ex^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{x}{\pi}}(\pi -x)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{\pi}}}{(12x+\pi )(13\pi -12x)}\quad 0\le x\le \pi .$$

> Can such a function —but one that is *exactly* $\sin x$ on the interval— exist? (Maximal absolute errors of the two functions above are $\approx 0.0016$ and $\approx 0.0318$, respectively.)
>
> It is known that no polynomial function alone can represent $\sin x$ on any non-zero continuous interval. But what about rational, exponential and logarithmic functions?

Comment: No rational function of $x$ alone can also represent $\sin x$ accurately. We know this from the fact that most values of $\sin x$ are irrational (indeed transcendental) for rational $x.$ Another surety that this cannot happen is from the Pade approximation to $\sin x,$ which is necessarily an infinite series of rational functions. As for whether real logarithms and exponentials suffice, I cannot say, though I highly doubt it -- as a matter of opinion.

Comment: Is there some mathematical term for the (unproved) impossibility of connecting a part of $\sin$ to finitely many combinations of real exponential and logarithmic functions? Because the nature of this problem is similar to that of *algebraic independence* for polynomial functions.

Comment: If the function is smooth and identical to $\sin x$ on some interval then it should the negative of it's second derivative and be equal to its own fourth derivative on that interval as well. Rational and logarithmic functions don't look much like their own derivatives.

Comment: That's an interesting way to think about it. Can such thought be somehow formulated as a rigorous proof of the impossibility?

Answer (score 1):

**comments.**  Still much left to do.

Suppose $F(x)$ is a function of your type defined on (at least) $[0,\pi]$, and suppose $F(x) = \sin x$ for all $x \in [0,\pi]$.  Let $a = \sup\{c : F \text{ is defined on }[0,c]\}$.  Since $F$ is given by formula of a certain kind, being "defined" at a point $x$ makes sense.

(1) If $F(x) = \sin x$ on $[0,\pi]$, then show $F(x) = \sin x$ on $[0,a)$.

(2) If $a=+\infty$ then $F$ has infinitely many zeros.  From that show $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

(3) If $a < + \infty$, then $F$ has a left-singularity at $a$ from a certain list of types of singularity, and therefore $\sin x$ has that same singularity, a contradiction.

Comment: So does this actually prove that no finite combination of rational, real exponential and logarithmic functions can represent $\sin x$ on a continuous interval? From Allawonder's comment I got the suspicion that it is currently unproved in mathematics (when it came to expressing one's "opinion").

Comment: No, it is just a suggestion of how to proceed, listing three things to prove.